# cannot convert from double to float

Tags: android, integer, division

In my database, I have a couple of "real" fields.

Heres the structure:

```
    database.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_LOGS + " (" 
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement," 
            + COLUMN_ID_DAY_EXERCISE + " integer not null,"
            + COLUMN_REPS + " integer not null"
            + COLUMN_WEIGHT + " real not null"
            + COLUMN_1RM + " real not null"
            + COLUMN_DATE + " integer not null"
            + ")");
```

Now what I am trying to do is calculate 1RM so that I can insert it into the database.

Here is my function so far:

```
public void createLog(long id_day_exercise, float reps, long weight) {

    // create 1rm
    // create date timestamp

    float onerm = weight/(1.0278-(.0278*reps));
    long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
}
```

I am stuck here. It is giving me the error "cannot convert from double to float" for `onerm`. I've tried casting the weight as a float by using (Float) in front of it, I've tried using weight.floatValue() and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
float onerm = (float) (weight / (1.0278 - (.0278 * reps)));
```

Answer (score 15):

What about this approach?

```
Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(your_double_variable));
```

Answer (score 10):

Casting from a double to a float can be done like this:

```
double d = 1.2;
float f = (float) d;
```

Or if you just need to express `1.2` as a float to start with, then use `1.2f`.

**Note**

- `float` is single-precision 32-bit and `double` is double-precision 64-bit so it is possible to lose precision in the conversion. See the [primitive data types documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: if lost precision is not a factor, this is by far the cleanest answer here

Answer (score 3):

In my case you have a `Double` variable, you can call `Double.floatValue()` like this:

```
Double deg = 45.0d;
float floatDeg = deg.floatValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `double` type is higher precision than `float`. You'll lose information when you make that assignment. That's why the compiler doesn't let you do that. It's similar to what happens when you want to do `char b = a` where a is an `int`.

Using an explicit cast might allow you to compile, but data/precision loss could happen.

EDIT:

Since in your original question all the inputs to the calculation are `floats`, use float literals. For example, `1.0278` is a double literal. I.e. append `f` to the constants such that all the calculations are floats and are not promoted to doubles:

```
float onerm = weight/(1.0278f-(.0278f*reps));
```

Comment: what do you recommend i do then?