# error: type mismatch : cannot convert from double to float

Tags: java, syntax-error

```java
float pen = 10.5;
```

Error message

```
type mismatch : cannot convert from double to float.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot convert from double to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513597/cannot-convert-from-double-to-float)

Comment: Btw.: You code in your question does not produce this error message, you would get the error message "possible lossy conversion from double to float" instead.

Answer (score 0):

`10.5` is a `double` literal. If you want a float add `f`.

```
float pen = 10.5f;
```